# How to syntax $state.go and refresh page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have pop up page that shows when you change the value of a toggle button.
The user gives some details in that pop up page. If the details are not correct, then the pop up should close, change the toggle button value to false and then reload the previous/main page (not the pop up page) so the toggle can get the new value(False)

Im trying to use this function:

```
    .finally(function() {
    console.log("Finally Function");

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.modal.hide();
        console.log($scope.value);
        $state.go($state.mainManu.logIn, {}, {reload: true});

     }, 3000);
   });
```

My route code is as follows:

```
  .state('mainManu.logIn', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/logIn.html',
        controller: 'logInCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

I know my state.go line is not correct, what is the correct syntax for that to work?

Comment: inject `$urlRouterProvider.` and use `  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `$state.go('mainManu.logIn');` and then I added `cache: false,` inside my routes state, So all the variables will be refreshed on the new page. Hope this solution will be helpful in the future.